# macOS, how to automatically mount and maintain the connection to an afp network drive?

Tags: mac, time-machine

When I mount an afp drive (for time machine) it will stay connected until the MacBook goes to sleep or some other interruption causes the connection to drop. What is the best way to maintain that connection so that I don't need to baby it to make sure my time machine backups complete?

Comment: You should be using SMB for Time Machine as AFP has been deprecated.  This connection should be managed automatically.

Comment: Fair enough! I guess i will reformat it as an smb share and see if that fixes the issues i was seeing

Comment: I set up a "whole home" Time Machine on the network that nobody used but on my iMac, it never lost connection.  I ended up getting rid of it for video storage and put the ownership of backup on each person in the house.  Bought them all a USB drive to be used for backup - not that they use that either, but at least I got my network storage real estate back.

Comment: I finally got it working through a combination of things. But it seems to be working well. I do see your point though if no one uses it. We only have two Macs in the house, but even if my mbp was the only one using it I would probably keep it on the network just because I hate having to plug in the drive. If my Mac was a desktop I would just leave a drive plugged in.